# "Save as" isn't automatically using the existing file name in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a "cmdFinished" button in Access which triggers qry_csvData and queries data in tbl_csvData, afterwards opens "Save As" dialog box. When "cmdFinished" is pushed and it opens "Save As" dialog box, the file name that is auto-populated is "qry_csvData" the triggered query file name. I would like the Filename in the dialog box to be auto-populated as "2023_ExcelData" and the file saved accordingly.
Below is what I currently have which works good except that i need to replace the Filename in the dialog box to the name I want the file save as:

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qry_csvData", acFormatXLSX (I do not need the file to open)
Is there anyway for changing the filename?

Comment: The outputfile parameter is probably what you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.outputto

Answer (score 0):

`DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qry_csvData", acFormatXLSX, Year(Now()) & "_ExcelData.xlsx"`

You don't need the Office Object Library when you use the FileDialog
this way:

```
With Application.FileDialog(2)
    .InitialFileName = Year(Now()) & "_ExcelData.xlsx"
    If .Show Then
       DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qry_csvData", acFormatXLSX, .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
```

more user friendly:

```
With Application.FileDialog(2)
    Dim sPath As String
    sPath = "" & DLookup("somefield", "sometable", "")
    If sPath = "" Then
       .InitialFileName = Year(Now()) & "_ExcelData.xlsx"
    Else
       .InitialFileName = sPath
    End If
    If .Show Then
       DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qry_csvData", acFormatXLSX, .SelectedItems(1)
       CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE sometable SET somefield='" & .SelectedItems(1) & "' WHERE true"
    End If
End With
```

To make it multi user, change "WHERE true" to the proper clause and also set the third argument of "DLookup"

Comment: Thanks Hennep for your quick response, what you suggested did not replace the filename in the "OutputTo"  dialog box.

Comment: The code I posted saves the output of the query as "2023_ExcelData.xlsx" in the documents folder. It does not show a save dialog. 
Can you add the code under the your button "cmdFinished" to your start post.

Comment: Yes you're right your code saves the output as "2023_ExcelData.xlsx"... What I'm trying to accomplish is to open the "Output To" dialog box with the name of the file already in the "Filename" so that the user only need to navigate to a desired folder. Thanks..

Comment: We still don't know what code you used for your SaveAs dialog. It would be easiest to correct your existing code but if we assume that you use Application.FileDialog, like BobS did below, then .InitialFileName is the solution. You can also make your code more user friendly by storing the whole path in a table and use that the next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `FileDialog` object to SaveAs then the following code will do this. You can also expand the `InitialFileName` value to include a default path. Note that you will need to set a reference to the Microsoft Office Object Library:

```
Public Sub sSaveAsDialog()

  Dim fdDialog As FileDialog

  Set fdDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

  With fdDialog

    'Set the title
    .Title = "Save Query As"

    'Set default file name
    .InitialFileName = Year(Now()) & "_ExcelData.xlsx"

    ' Execute the file dialog
    If .Show Then
      DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qry_csvData", acFormatXLSX, .SelectedItems(1)
    End If

  End With

End Sub
```

If you don't want to set a reference to the MS Office object library then replace the `DIM` and `SET` lines with the following three lines of code:

```
  Dim fdDialog As Object

  Const lngSaveAs As Long = 2
  Set fdDialog = Application.FileDialog(lngSaveAs)
```